# Clear all Child Node and node Value of xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Does any one know how to remove contents of all child nodes in xml using xslt transformation.

**Source Code**

```
  <TotalResponse id="TE2146D7766F24FE683090325091EE0B4">
     <TotalCovIA27_CrimeResponse id="T8550FBBC76364CA699158D4087059F9A">
          <CovIA27_CrimeResponse>
            <instance>
              <CovGroupType>i8BE0F604FF6F44AEB3C36271DCBB7204</CovGroupType>
              <CovID>r67F85BB6345E4D3893C25D1B47FA7E32</CovID>
              <CovType>add</CovType>
            </instance>
          </CovIA27_CrimeResponse>
        </TotalCovIA27_CrimeResponse>
        <TotalCovIA28_CrimeResponse id="T257F4902E7214C58ABD9258860CB6C24">
          <CovIA28_CrimeResponse>
            <instance>
              <CovGroupType>i2880CCCAB9D045A3A7FFFCB6AE0C05C7</CovGroupType>
              <CovID>rED310B0934534A8BA1CA2B5CB0BA77E5</CovID>
              <CovType>modify</CovType>
            </instance>
            <change>
              <ChangeFieldID>IA28ForgeryAndAlterationInput.Limit</ChangeFieldID>
              <ChangeNewValue>131334</ChangeNewValue>
            </change>
          </CovIA28_CrimeResponse>
        </TotalCovIA28_CrimeResponse>

  </TotalResponse>
```

**Expected output 1**

```
<TotalResponse id="TE2146D7766F24FE683090325091EE0B4">
     <TotalCovIA27_CrimeResponse id="T8550FBBC76364CA699158D4087059F9A">
          <CovIA27_CrimeResponse>
            <instance>
              <CovGroupType></CovGroupType>
              <CovID></CovID>
              <CovType></CovType>
            </instance>
          </CovIA27_CrimeResponse>
        </TotalCovIA27_CrimeResponse>
        <TotalCovIA28_CrimeResponse id="T257F4902E7214C58ABD9258860CB6C24">
          <CovIA28_CrimeResponse>
            <instance>
              <CovGroupType></CovGroupType>
              <CovID></CovID>
              <CovType></CovType>
            </instance>
            <change>
              <ChangeFieldID></ChangeFieldID>
              <ChangeNewValue></ChangeNewValue>
            </change>
          </CovIA28_CrimeResponse>
        </TotalCovIA28_CrimeResponse>

  </TotalResponse>
```

**Expected Output 2**

```
<TotalResponse id="TE2146D7766F24FE683090325091EE0B4">
     <TotalCovIA27_CrimeResponse id="T8550FBBC76364CA699158D4087059F9A">
          <CovIA27_CrimeResponse>
            <instance\>  
          </CovIA27_CrimeResponse>
        </TotalCovIA27_CrimeResponse>
        <TotalCovIA28_CrimeResponse id="T257F4902E7214C58ABD9258860CB6C24">
          <CovIA28_CrimeResponse>
            <instance/>                               
            <change/>  
          </CovIA28_CrimeResponse>
       </TotalCovIA28_CrimeResponse>
  </TotalResponse>
```

Both the output will satisfy my requirement but i prefer Output 1.

**Note:** Total Response is the dynamic parent root name which changes based on the output of other xslt's.

Comment: You first have to clarify what you want.  How do your (or your XSL processor) identify the elements to be modified?  Do you even need to identify them? For example, would it be acceptable to to strip all `text()` nodes from the document?  And what have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, you want a "special treatment" for children of
`instance` and `change` elements.

In the first variant you want to leave only the tags without
their content and in the second variant omit these elements
altogether.

So the solution for the first case is a template matching
child elements of `instance` and `change` whatever they are.
The content of this template should include only `<xsl:copy/>`,
i.e. make only a *shallow copy* of these elements.

The script must include also an identity template.

Below you have a solution for the first variant:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="instance/* | change/*">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**How it works:**

Lets start from the end - the *identity template* (`match="node() | @*"`).
It copies all source content to the output.
This is the "most general" template, serving all nodes not served by other
(more specific) templates. For more details search the web.

Now move on to the template matching `"instance/* | change/*"`.
The `match` clause contains 2 parts: `instance/*` and `change/*`
separated with a `|` (a *sum* operator for both above *XPath* expressions).

It means: this template will serve each element which is either
a child of `instance` or a child of `change` (and the identity template
described above will not serve (will not be applied to) them).

Now move on to the content of this template: `<xsl:copy/>`.
This command performs so called *shallow copy*, i.e. it copes to the
output only an empty "original" tag.
E.g. source element `<CovID>r67F8...7E32</CovID>` will be output as
`<CovID/>`. For more details you can also search the web.

One more remark concerning fine details:

If you tried this script and you are observant, you may have noticed that instead of e.g. `<CovID></CovID>` the output contained `<CovID/>`.

No problem, from the "XML point of view" this is the same, but shorter.
And this is just the way how (I suppose all) XSLT processors generate
empty elements.

And if you wanted to receive **Expected output 2** (your second variant),
then remove `<xsl:copy/>` from the template matching children of
`instance` and `change`.

Actually, you can write this template in even more concise way:

```
<xsl:template match="instance/* | change/*"/>
```

so you get an *empty* or *do nothing* template.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Can You provide me explanation also, as i am new to xslt and not able to understand it working.

Comment: Why did you say "Let start from the last", does xslt always start from the last or is just this only this xslt?

Comment: I thought, the explanation would be more natural if I started from the identity template.

Answer (score 0):

> how to remove contents of all child nodes in xml

It's not clear what you mean by "child nodes". It looks like you simply want to remove all text nodes from the input - which is very easy to do using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This simply copies elements and their attributes and discards nodes of any other type.